# Flutter Live location in Background

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I want to achieve live location tracking for one of our internal flutter application.It is a internal team application, where we should be able to track and push the location of our team member to our backend servers at a frequency of 30sec. This should be available even if the application goes into the background. Need a free solution.

Thank you in advance

I tried few flutter plugins like location, background_location, geolocation but it did not workout

Answer (score 1):

Use this package [location: ^5.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/location) and Try with this code:

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';

Future<LocationData?> getCurrentLocation() async {
  Location location = Location();
  bool serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus permissionStatus;

  try {
    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        // Service not enabled, handle accordingly
        return null;
      }
    }

    permissionStatus = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionStatus = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        // Permission not granted, handle accordingly
        return null;
      }
    }
    
    return await location.getLocation();
  } catch (e) {
    logE(message: 'Error getting current location: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```

How to call:

```
getCurrentLocation().then((location) {
  if (location != null) {
    // Use location here
    print(location.latitude ?? 0);
    print(location.longitude ?? 0);
  } else {
    print('Getting error on fetch');
  }
}).onError((error, stackTrace) {
  print('onError $error');
});
```

*Make sure device location is enabled.*

## Updated:

**Use This package to manage the app when it comes in the background**
Package name: `move_to_background`
[Package Link](https://pub.dev/packages/move_to_background)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but i think you did not read my question properly. The goal is to capture background location meaning capturing location on a timely frequency even when the app is in the background. Eg: I will have to capture the location every 15 secs, when the app is wither in foreground or background.
I have already explored location plugin. It is not capturing location the background

Comment: Okay, Understand. Please use `move_to_background 1.0.2` package to manage the background things.